# Excel vlookup with address parameter

Tags: excel, vlookup

A cousin of mine asked me if i could help him with a function in Excel but i cant make it work.
I have a function which is:

```
=VLOOKUP(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+1;4);Sheet3!A2:B48;2)
```

the problem is that for the first parameter i am using the address function which works like an individual function but inside vlookup it returns the answer with quotation with result vlookup to stop working.

For example: if i run the function:

`=ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+1;4)`

in A6 cell the result will be B6.

But inside the vlookup will return "B6".

Do you know any way to get the B6 answer inside the vlookup and not the"B6"?

Thanks!

Comment: So why can't you just put B6?

Comment: Note that failing to include FALSE as he *range_lookup* parameter of the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) means that Sheet3!A2:A48 must be sorted or returned results will be unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the INDIRECT() function:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()+1;4));Sheet3!A2:B48;2)
```